# Why is this PHP "in_array" not working with SQL query?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Hello I have some wordpress posts with a custom field titled, "Incentive ID".  I have a php/sql query that returns a comma separated list of "recommended" "Incentive ID's"

```
global $wpdb;
$user_ID = get_current_user_id();
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(T_L_INCENTIVES_ID) 
FROM incentive_recommendations_v 
WHERE accept_recommendation = 1 AND user_id = $user_ID
SQL;

if (!$sql) { // add this check.
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

$resultset = array();
$rebates = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, ARRAY_A );
foreach($rebates as $data) {
     $resultset[] = $data['GROUP_CONCAT(T_L_INCENTIVES_ID)'];
}
```

I want to populate a special "medal" icon on each of the posts whose custom field value "Incentive ID" is contained in the comma separated list of "Recommended" Incentive IDs.  For this I am attempting to use "in_array" like so

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<li style="margin-bottom:20px;">
<?php echo $resultset;?><br>
<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Incentive ID', true);?>
<div title="Recommended Incentive" <?php $incent = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Incentive ID', true); if ( in_array($incent,$resultset)) { 
echo'style="background-image:url(/images/gold_medal.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:10% auto; background-position:right top; border:2px solid #ccc; padding:20px 48px 20px 20px; height:auto; padding-bottom:20px; min-height:260px !important;"';
} else { 
echo 'style="border:2px solid #ccc; padding:20px 48px 20px 20px; height:auto; padding-bottom:20px; min-height:260px !important;"';}  ?> >
```

However, I can't get the Gold Medal icons to display at all, even on posts that I know contain the correct "Incentive ID".  The error I receive says that

```
in_array expects parameter 2 to be array, string given.
```

Any help that can be given on this problem would be much appreciated!

Comment: You have no GROUP BY clause in your query, what exactly are you expecting your query to do? Also, your `if (!sql) {...}` is doing nothing at all, as the variable `$sql` is always going to be defined there, yet no query has been run at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove the `GROUP_CONCAT()` from your `SELECT` statement
Then add add a `GROUP BY` to the `SELECT` statement as well.
Here is the code for the `SELECT` statement and converting it to an array.

```
global $wpdb;
$user_ID = get_current_user_id();
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT T_L_INCENTIVES_ID
FROM incentive_recommendations_v 
WHERE accept_recommendation = 1 AND user_id = $user_ID
GROUP BY T_L_INCENTIVES_ID
SQL;

if (!$sql) { // add this check.
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

$resultset = array();
$rebates = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, ARRAY_A );
foreach($rebates as $data) {
     $resultset[] = $data['T_L_INCENTIVES_ID'];
}
```

Then change your code to this for populating your "gold medal" icon

```
<?php $incent = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Incentive ID', true); if ( in_array($incent,$resultset)) { 
          echo'style="background-image:url(/images/gold_medal.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:10% auto; background-position:right top; border:2px solid #ccc; padding:20px 48px 20px 20px; height:auto; padding-bottom:20px; min-height:260px !important;"';
          } else { 
          echo 'style="border:2px solid #ccc; padding:20px 48px 20px 20px; height:auto; padding-bottom:20px; min-height:260px !important;"';}  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP_CONCAT()` is going to produce a string, so your DB results will look like

```
$rows = array(
   '0' => array('foo' => '1,2,3,4'),
   '1' => array('bar' => '5,6,7,8')
);
```

You're literally trying to do `in_array(3, '1,2,3,4')`. Since `1,2,3,4` is a string, you get your warning. You'd need to `explode()` that string, THEN do your in_array on the array you get from explode(). or just don't do `group_concat` in the DB and fetch individual records into an array you build in your while/fetch loop.